# iOS Static Library Xcode (linking errors)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, static-libraries

I created a static library with Xcode I have compiled selecting a device.

I added this to my library test project in Xcode 4.6

but I always have 2 errors during the linking...

I followed this tutorial: [Static Library iOS Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

if I download the sample code I have the same errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Downloads/ICodeBlogStaticLibrarySample/MathTest/Classes/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Downloads/ICodeBlogStaticLibrarySample/MathTest/Classes/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MathFunctions", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MathTestAppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: which errors? because "2 errors during the linking" is not informative at all.

Comment: Two errors. 1. Missing `;` and 2. Solve first error.

Comment: Just a note of sympathy:  Static libraries suck in Xcode.

Comment: @HotLicks Is there anything that does not suck in Xcode? (Well, to be fair, at least the syntax highlighting/autoindentation is quite good, but the rests sucks, really.)

Comment: Static libraries outsuck most everything else.

Comment: @HotLicks Personally, I hate that specifying custom compiler flags is much more (over)complicated that it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this step by step tutorial:

[Tutorial](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules)

in particular I had to add these flags: `-ObjC` and `-all_load`

Comment: So, what did you add them to?

Answer (score 1):

I had once made a static lirary , I had the same problem .
Solution was to "Run the app on device " not on simulator , it works fine then !!!
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You must have selected iOS simulator while building the project. Select iOS device and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do read and try to understand the error message, it's a meaningful English phrase.

> symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

So there's no compiled code for the i386 architecture in the library. This means that either it's compiled for ARM only (for actual iOS devices, like iPhone or iPad), or for the 64-bit simulator (x86_64). Use `otool` to find out the architectures present in the library.

Comment: Yeah, but try to figure out which of the 3492 different knobs in Xcode to turn to fix it.